# What is the equivalent DataWeave type for Typescript's Record<string, any>?

Tags: dataweave, anypoint-studio, mule4

[DataWeave](https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev-guides/how-to-tutorials/dataweave-type-system/) has a type declaration system similar to [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html).

I want to define a DataWeave type that is equivalent to Typescript's `Record<string, V>`.

Specifically, I want to define a map-like type wherein I do not know the specific keys but I do know that they are Strings, and I do know what the values will be.

For example:

```js
{
  "foo": { "answer": 42 },
  "bar": { "answer": 1337 },
  "this key could be any string": { "answer": 1 }
}
```

---

#### What I've tried

Per [DataWeave's v2.3 documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.3/dataweave-type-system#object-type), I can declare an `object` type as:

```js
type User = {
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    age: Number
}
```

However, that assumes I know what the keys in that object are, namely `firstName`, `lastName`, and `age`. In my use case, I do not know what the keys are, only that they are strings.

Thanks

Comment: why do you need to do it in DataWeave? what's the need or requirement?

Comment: @aled - I would like AnypointStudio to provide autocompletion and type checking to my script to make it easier for me to write it and check my syntax. Thanks

Comment: See my answer to your question. Having said that, Anypoint Studio 7.11 has some improvements in DataWeave editing, though I'm not sure they address what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reviewing the autogenerated types in my Mule4 project at `src/main/resources/weave/autogenerated`, I discovered that unknown key properties are represented by `_` (underscore).

Example:

```
type Foo = {
    _: {
        name: String
    }
}

var myfoo: Foo = {
    "a": {
        name: "aa"
    },
    "b": {
        name: "bb"
    }
}
```

DataWeave will now autosuggest `name` property when you write `myfoo['any string here'].`

[image: dataweave autocomplete]

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of [Objects](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.3/dataweave-types#dw_type_object) in DataWeave keys are of type `Key` and can not be of arbitrary types. A Key contains a name and attributes, and the name is always a `String`. I understand that that means that Objects are by default basically equivalent to what you want to achieve. Actually it doesn't seem to be possible to define objects with a different kind of keys.

> Object (dw::Core Type)
>
> Represents any object as a collection of Key:value pairs, where a Key
> is composed of a Name and Attributes.
>
> The Name type is composed of a String as the local name and the
> Namespace. Attributes is composed of an Array of Name:value pairs.
> Note that the Key is not a String, so it is not possible to compare
> keys. However, you can get the local name by performing an as String
> type coercion on any value of type Key.

Comment: Thanks. Could you also provide an example of how to define a `type` in the **header** section of a DataWeave script? I see from the link you provided how in the **body** of my DataWeave script I can generate an object response.